# Tried upgrading React Native to latest version but after the upgrade the application crashes on start - couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so

Tags: android, react-native

I attempted to upgrade React Native to the latest version using `npx react-native upgrade` but unfortunately afterwards my application began crashing every time I attempted to open it. The error I am receiving in logcat is the following:

```
2022-07-19 17:59:29.656 5839-5839/com.test.debug E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so
        SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~LUHA0j7Q5CamOcaNiTfm-A==/com.test.debug-B9LWM9Y6WT48CixnKRvVMg==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
        SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectApkSoSource[root = /data/app/~~LUHA0j7Q5CamOcaNiTfm-A==/com.test.debug-B9LWM9Y6WT48CixnKRvVMg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a]
        SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
        SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
        Native lib dir: /data/app/~~LUHA0j7Q5CamOcaNiTfm-A==/com.test.debug-B9LWM9Y6WT48CixnKRvVMg==/lib/arm64
     result: 0
```

I attempted navigating to the Android folder and running `gradlew clean` but that didn't help. I had a couple of small conflicts which I resolved after executing `npx react-native upgrade` and I can't figure out if the problem stems from that.

Answer (score 1):

With upgrading React Native, there are a lot of other files and modifications that could be missing. Have you tried React Native Upgrade Helper? You put the version you were at and which version you want to go to and it gives you all the changes and deletions needed to make the jump. That might solve the small errors so you can narrow down the root cause.

[React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/)

Or you could try updating the SO Loader in your android/app/build.gradle as this Stack Overflow post mentions: [Update SO Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524006/e-soloader-couldnt-find-dso-to-load-libjscexecutor-so) You will just have to find the recent version of SO Loader as this post was from 2020.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to upgrade react-native-reanimated to the latest version.